# Laravel 12s boot

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I'm having some trouble getting Laravel to boot. Each page loaded has a huge delay. The boot time for Laravel is 12s (before any routes are loaded). Connecting to mysql w/ PDO takes 3 seconds on its own. However, connecting to the mysql server without laravel does not create any issues.

I know there are a lot of possible variables at play here, but I am looking for any suggestions. I have spent a few hours trying to solve this issue with no luck.

Comment: Is it clean Laravel installation? If not, try with fresh installation and compare what modifications have you done

Comment: It is not a clean installation. Will try this - thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: of course try first what's the time for fresh installation. It should be really low. If it's not probably that's your server settings